# Extract the Crosstalk noise of a circuit in Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-gate

I'm new to Quantum Computing. How to extract the cross-talk noise of a quantum circuit using qiskit? Can someone provide an example code for this?

Comment: Hi @Raghul K and welcome! Could you add a little bot more details to your question? In particular, I think it would be helpful to define the notion of "cross-talk noise of a quantum circuit" because in the definition I know, cross-talk noise is a property of the underlying chip and is not impacted by the actual circuit ran (here I mean that the *error rates* due to cross-talk are not impacted).

Comment: Thank you @AdrienSuau. So in other words give a quantum hardware how can I calculate the cross talk. I was exploring IBMQ publicly available machines. For example, let's take IBMQ Melbourne, for this machine how am I supposed to estimate the cross talk error.